# how to connect to my home computer when i was at company

Tags: networking, nat

i want to connect to my home's computer when i was at another place .but my home's computer is behind a router.and i can't set the router , cause it is not my. any way i can let my home's computer visible to the global internet , so i can find it at another place?
my friends told me use NAT traversal  . but i don't know how to implement it .

any one could help me ?
thank you .

i use gentoo linux os ,
and i just want to connect to my home's computer use ssh , so i can control my home's computer .

Comment: You don't say what you want to do when you connect, and you don't say what the OS is (I suspect windows?).  That'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/pl/index.aspx), this app allow to conect even if you have dynamic ip.

Comment: it seems teamviewer is not free , and i want to do it myself .

Answer (score 0):

SSH, NAT traversal ? Sounds strange.

All you need to do is TCP & UDP forward port 22 (SSH) to your Linux box's internal IP.
Then, you also need to tell your router to always give the same internal IP to your Linux box (via MAC address or netbios [=computer] name).

You can use TightVNC for remote-controlling X11 (you need to port-forward the VNC port (5900 and also 5500 and 5800).

Another option is to use x-forwarding with SSH.

```
(ssh root@YourDomainOrIP.com -X)
```

And you can also use sshfs, if you only want to access your files.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sshfs
sshfs username@targetip:/ /mnt/sshfs
```

On a sidenote: Make sure you only use 4096 bit RSA private/public key authentication on SSH. No passwords, or you will get brute-force hacked in no time with absolute certainty.

(my SSH logs shows about 4000+ distinct hack attempts in the last 6 months, which means 22 distinct attempts per day...)